# jquery mouseenter is not working for specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Click here to view the demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFeODTMmKjSPFCdouCHA?p=preview)

Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".works").mouseenter(function(e) {

        $( ".img_details" ).stop().animate({ 'bottom':'5%', 'opacity':'1'},500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $( ".works").mouseleave(function(e) {

        $( ".img_details" ).stop().animate({ 'bottom':'100%', 'opacity':'0'},500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

There are two divs with the class name "works" which holds one div that has the class name "img_details". If mouse pointer enters into the first div "img_details" also load in both divs. I want to load once the specific div. What did I miss?

Comment: In both handlers use `$(".img_details", this).sto...`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `this`, `this` will point to the current object, here it will be the currently hovered `.works`, then you find the specific `.img_details` inside `this` and animate that element only.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".works").mouseenter(function(e) {

        $(this).find( ".img_details" ).stop().animate({ 'bottom':'5%', 'opacity':'1'},500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $( ".works").mouseleave(function(e) {

        $(this).find( ".img_details" ).stop().animate({ 'bottom':'100%', 'opacity':'0'},500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tugaCPa4L6mQvAtvQN3u?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the contextual `this`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".works").mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).find(".img_details").stop().animate({
      'bottom': '5%',
      'opacity': '1'
    }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(".works").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).find(".img_details").stop().animate({
      'bottom': '100%',
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**Reason:** When you are giving `.works` again, it targets every `.works` in the document. But when you give `this` **inside the callback function**, it refers only to the current `<div>` where the `mouseenter` is happened. This is a common mistake done by all the newbies of jQuery. `:)`

**Output: http://plnkr.co/edit/bKc00tEebxs9TAONBid4?p=preview**

Answer (score 2):

`( ".img_details" )` will select all `div` having class `img_details`. You should find the `img_details` under `works` and use animation on it like following.

```
$(".works").mouseenter(function(e) {    
    $(this).find( ".img_details" ).stop().animate({ 'bottom':'5%', 'opacity':'1'},500);
    e.preventDefault();
});

$( ".works").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).find( ".img_details" ).stop().animate({ 'bottom':'100%', 'opacity':'0'},500);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HO7PuyfFwNZj4rpWJwU4?p=preview